# copy projects from farm 2013 to 2016

Tags: project

I have a project server farm 2016, I need to only copy projects with its project site (about 100 projects) from my old farm 2013 to the new farm

I don't want to do full migration, only Enterprise projects with sites need to copy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** there is no straightforward way to achieve your goal!

---

**You have two options:**

1. **Boring Manually Option**

   - Manually Save all Projects Schedule and Upload it to the destination Project Server 2016 farm using `Microsoft Project`.
   - Then Import and export the Projects Subsites using PowerShell.
2. **Migration Option**

   - Migrate Project Content Database from Project Server 2013 to Project Server 2016. for the detail steps check, **[Migrate to Project Server 2016 Step By Step](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/10/30/project-server-2016-migration/)**

> **Note:** this option will lead to removing all settings that have been
>   implemented in Project Server 2016 like Permission Settings, New
>   Lists, sites, current projects...etc

Check also **[Install and configure Project Server 2016.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/install-and-configure-project-server-2016/)**